# How do I fix this Macro to CONCATENATE and then paste values of two columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste

I'm trying to write a macro in gsheets that will concatenate two columns and then copy the values back over to the first column. But everything I try the copy to column just gets blanked out.

```
function CopyandPasteValues() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('H2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=CONCATENATE(E2,"",G2)');
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('H2:H249'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
  spreadsheet.getRange('H2:H249').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('E2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('H2:H249').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};
```

Comment: I solved it...
I moved the "SpreadsheetApp.flush();" to before activating E2 and it worked fine.
Thank for letting me talk it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the values, try the the following:

```
function CopyandPasteValues() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var values = spreadsheet.getRange('E2:G249').getDisplayValues();
  var output = values.map(row => row[0] + row[2]);
  spreadsheet.getRange('H2:H249').setValues(output);
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks clean. I'll give it a try